# Scope chains in object literals

Tags: javascript, oop, object, scope-chain

```
var x = 9;
var mod = {
    x: 81,
    assign: function(){
        this.x = 9;
        x = 3;
    },
    checkVars: function(){
        alert(x + " - " + this.x );
    }
};

mod.checkVars(); //9 - 81

mod.assign();
mod.checkVars(); //3 - 9

alert(x); //3
```

Please explain how does scope chains set themselves here. And why does scope resolution for `x` in `checkVars` and `assign` skip the object `mod`?

Comment: `mod` doesn't have a variable called `x`.  It has a *property* called `x`.

Comment: I never said `x` is a variable. `checkVars` is just a fancy name, if you meant it.

Comment: What you seem to be missing is that scope chains only apply to variables, not properties (the prototype chain applies to those).

Comment: @bfavaretto You are right. You made a good hint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables and object properties are not the same thing. Variables are part of scope chains, properties are not. The only variables in scope of `assign` and `checkVars` are `x` and `mod`.  The properties of `mod` are only visible from within those methods via `this.propName` (or `mod.propName`).

Answer (score 5):

I've added some comments to your program:

```
var x = 9; // This is the *only* variable called x in your program
var mod = {
    x: 81, // this x refers to a property of mod also called x
    assign: function(){
        this.x = 9; // "this" refers to the object mod, this.x is the x property of mod
        x = 3; // x here refers to your variable called x
    },
    checkVars: function(){
        alert(x + " - " + this.x ); // same as above
    }
};

mod.checkVars(); //9 - 81

mod.assign();
mod.checkVars(); //3 - 9

alert(x); //3
```

In other words, your confusion doesn't have anything to do with scope resolution.  Any time you reference `x`, you're referring to the one and only variable called `x` you defined at the top of your program.  Any time you refer to `this.x`, you're referring to the property called `x` you defined on the `mod` object literal.

Hope this helps clarify things!

Comment: `this x refers to your variable called x`  maybe you should change it to: `x here refers to your variable called x` - Just to eliminate any misunderstandings about "this x" and `this.x`

Comment: @NULL - Heh, yes that might be less confusing.

Comment: Actually there is *some* scope resolution going on. There is no local `x` inside the functions, and `x` is found in the parent level of the scope chain.

Comment: @bfavaretto - Eh, I figured people would know what I meant.  But I've changed the wording.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes I'm too picky and don't even notice it... Sorry about that.

Comment: Simply speaking within an object literal , to access its properties in your case x of mod, you have to use "this" to define context